Can you predict with an AR model to replace missing data for a year?
Income data for 2023 is missing in my dataset because the official statistics bureau hasn't published that yet and won't for a while. My thesis adviser suggested I use an AR(2) model to predict 1-year ahead to 2023. The dataset is a panel data and I'm concerned with stationarity, as income doesn't tend to be stationary. Is it still reliable if it's non-stationary?
Other methods to predict 1-year ahead?

An "integrated" autoregression is one where the model is run on differenced values. In order to make the series stationary, please use differenced values, in an ARIMA model (the I in ARIMA stands for integrated).
